# How can I use <tables> like HTML in CActiveForm classin Yii to align my lables and textboxes?

Tags: php, yii

Here is the sample code where I have made a dropdown, two textboxes and a button.Now how can I align them using tables like we use to do in HTML.

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'user_id');?>
    <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'user_id',array('All'=>'All','Members'=>'Members','BusinessUsers'=>'BusinessUsers','SelectedUsers'=>'SelectedUsers'));?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'user_id'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'title'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'title'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'title'); ?>
</div>


<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'message'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'message'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'message'); ?>
</div>


<div class="row buttons">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Send Message'); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Just create an html table with tr's and td's and then place the php blocks in the td's

Comment: i tried but it still doesn't work.....can u please show me how to do this on one of my blocks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but should work like this.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'user_id');?></td>
            <td><?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'user_id',array('All'=>'All','Members'=>'Members','BusinessUsers'=>'BusinessUsers','SelectedUsers'=>'SelectedUsers'));?></td>
            <td><?php echo $form->error($model,'user_id'); ?></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```